# rowspan changes the all td heights in Internet Explorer

Tags: html

good morning. i have a table next to it one advertisement picture 160 X 600 pixel, i used rowspan to avoid the td next to it to get height 600 pixel such as the ad image and here is my code

```
  <tr align="center">
  <td style="border:2px solid #00FFFF;width:500;height:36;" align="center" valign="center"><font face="arial" size="5" color="#33FFFF"><b>إسم البرنامج</b></td>
  <td style="border:2px solid #00FFFF;width:130;height:36;" align="center" valign="center"><font face="arial" size="5" color="#33FFFF"><b>تاريخ الإضافة</b></td>
  <td style="border:2px solid #00FFFF;width:120;height:36;" align="center" valign="center"><font face="arial" size="5" color="#33FFFF"><b>مرات العرض</b></td>
  <td style="border:2px solid #00FFFF;width:130;height:36;" align="center" valign="center"><font face="arial" size="5" color="#33FFFF"><b>يعمل بنسبة %</b></td>
  <td rowspan=36 style="border:0px solid #00FFFF;width:160;height:600;"><a href="link" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="160x600.2.gif" width="160" height="600" title="" /></a></td>
  </tr>
```

and this is a drawing, every thing works fine

```
|"""""""| |""""""|"""""""|""""""""""|""""""""""|
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

this is as shown above in all web browsers is fine but in Internet Explorer shows it as:

```
|"""""""| |""""""|"""""""|""""""""""|""""""""""|
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |      |       |          |          |
|       | |______|_______|__________|__________|
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

i hope to see it works fine in Internet Explorer such as the Other web browsers as the first drawing, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the px unit from your width/heights, e.g.

```
width:500;height:36;
```

should be

```
width:500px;height:36px;
```

You should also use css for this, e.g.

```
<style type="text/css">
td { border:2px solid #00FFFF;width:500px;height:36px; }
td:last-child { border:0px solid #00FFFF;width:160px;height:600px; }
</style>
```

Comment: i put the px but no thing changed, also css for this changes the page for the worse

Answer (score 0):

1. It is usually recommended not to use `table`s for layout purpose.
2. You have not shown structure of remaining `TR`s
3. If you still want to go ahead with `table` I'll recommend following structure

> ```
> <tr>
> <td>
>     <table>
>     <tr align="center">
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr align="center">
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>         <td>data</td>
>     </tr>
>     <table>
> </td>
> <td>
>     <img 160x600>
> </td>
> </tr>
> ```

This way the height of outer table will be 600px due to image, but the height of inner table will remain small according to the data.

Comment: i have the remaining of the table code, but i submitted a part of it "which containing the problem"

Comment: Did you try using nested table?

Comment: No i didn't try, but i don't know, what is the problem with internet explorer